# Excel conditional read-only fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel document, where based on a cell's value, I should enable or disable some cells in a row, let's say the condition equals 1, then in the condition's row, two fields should be editable, the rest should be read only. I tried to apply validation to the fields but I can't seem to figure out the formula. How should I make the F1 field read only when the condition is 1 but editable when not? I should check whether the condition is empty and a specific value.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, you are confusing formatting (the appearance of a cell - font, colours, background, etc) with protection/locking (the ability to make a cell edittable or read-only). Conditional formatting allows a cell's format to be dynamically changed but this does not extend to protection/locking. What you require is achievable - but only using VBA and a worksheet change event.

Comment: Custom data validation is not related to appearance of the cell. If I type in a custom rule like `=""`, it makes the field read only all the time. (And you can set the field to Date/Decimal/List.. http://www.excel-easy.com/basics/data-validation.html ). Also, it is not my intention to make the cell's background grey, it was just an example for which values should be readonly fields. Also, it is not related to the conditional formatting function, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you shouldn't be able to do this.

If you have your custom rule for F1 as:-

```
=B3<>1
```

and B3 contains

```
=A3
```

Then if A3 is set to 1, you won't be able to type anything into F1, but if it is set to anything else, you will be able to type any value into F1.

You could set a rule

```
=C3<>1
```

for F2, etc. but it would be easier if the conditions were arranged column-wise so you could copy the rules for F1 down to other cells in column F.

[image]